# On combinations of planar graphs of given number of vertices of given valences

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

Good evening,

I am new at the MSE, I signed up just now, so I greet you all; please bare with the newcomer.

I have a graph theory problem, which has come up in an entirely different context, a problem in Mathematical Physics. As I am not familiar with graph theory, I decided to post this question, being fully aware that, in my ignorance, I am unable to assess this problem anywhere between trivial and  impossible... Here goes:

***Consider a set of vertices on the plane; specifically, $N_A$ vertices of valence 4, and $N_B$ vertices of valence 1. How many planar, connected graphs can one construct with the given vertices, up to isomorphism?***

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't see that baring with the newcomer would be regarded as socially acceptable. Public nudity and all. Plus, we have not been properly introduced. Bearing with might work.

Comment: Actually it looks to me like mathematical chemistry: you're trying to count planar saturated hydrocarbon molecules with $N_A$ carbons and $N_B$ hydrogens.  I don't know the answer: I suspect it is hard in general.

Comment: **Will Jagy** - The newcomer stands corrected...! Forgive the error.
**Robert Israel** - Interesting remark, even though the original problem has nothing to do with Chemistry.

Comment: @MathPhys How large will $N_A$ and $N_B$ get? Do you want just to count (enumerate) them, or could you conceivably list them and count them?

Comment: @gilleain - $N_A$ can be any natural number, while $N_B$ clearly cannot be odd. I would like an explicit counting formula for arbitrary values of the above; I am not interested in listing them.

Comment: @MathPhys I suspected so. I don't know enough about explicit formulae for counting this class of graphs, so I can't justify this as an answer, but did you see http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605218 ? The maths there is beyond me, but seems very physics-oriented. I understand that in genreal this problem is quite hard - indeed, may still be unsolved.